# Error when compiling with Gradle (can't find downloaded dependencies)

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, gradlew, gradle-plugin

I develop an app generation system that is regenerating apps by command line Gradle compilation commands.

In my Windows Server 2008, I'm facing a problem after updating to the last Gradle version and Gradle plugin version.

When compiling I'm getting this errors:

```
C:\Windows\System32\config\systemprofile\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\appcompat-v7-25.0.0.aar\e93435c34d5cae8b6677dcef529711a5\res\drawable-xxhdpi-v4\abc_text_select_handle_middle_mtrl_light.png: error: file not found.

C:\Windows\System32\config\systemprofile\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\appcompat-v7-25.0.0.aar\e93435c34d5cae8b6677dcef529711a5\res\drawable\abc_btn_colored_material.xml: error: file not found.

C:\Windows\System32\config\systemprofile\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\appcompat-v7-25.0.0.aar\e93435c34d5cae8b6677dcef529711a5\res\drawable-hdpi-v4\abc_textfield_search_default_mtrl_alpha.9.png: error: file not found.

and a lot more of errors like those...
```

I'm not sure why I'm getting this error, because the file is correctly downloaded and it's correctly located on that exactly direction.

It has a path length of 204 characters, so supposedly it's not surpassing the limit of 255 path characters on NTFS Windows file system.

It is possible to change the location where Gradle downloads it's cached dependencies? Is this problem caused by this or by other thing?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

finally i solved this setting the environmental variable GRADLE_USER_HOME in windows to c:/gradle-cache

so definitively it's related to file path lenght

Comment: That saved my day!! Literally the whole day trying to figure out why this was happening. The error would only happen for me building from Jenkins. Running the same cli command from cmd in Windows at same path would build with no errors though.

Answer (score 2):

I meet this same error in windows jenkins

I solved this error.

```
gradle assembleDebug -g C:\gradle-cache
```

-g:

```
gradle -h

-g, --gradle-user-home    Specifies the gradle user home directory
```

Answer (score 0):

Path length cause failure.

I defined

```
"-Dorg.gradle.user.home=%GRADLE_USER_HOME%"
```

in gradle run parameters and it solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

2023 Update:

If you want to do this through Android Studio go to

**Settings -> Build, Execution, Deployment -> Build Tools -> Gradle -> Gradle user home [textbox]**