# Jenkins Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources' , file not found

Tags: android, jenkins, gradle, build.gradle

I have been trying to build an Android application using Jenkins. I am getting Jenkins Execution failed for task `:app:mergeDebugResources`. I do have admin privilege but console output saying file not found. I have attached console output for reference. Please help.

```
Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2Exception: Android resource compilation failed
Output:  C:\Windows\System32\config\systemprofile\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\appcompat-v7-28.0.0-alpha3.aar\6bb4f54973fdd09ea38bd7415ec1d0d5\res\layout\abc_action_bar_up_container.xml: error: file not found.
Command: C:\Windows\System32\config\systemprofile\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\aapt2-3.2.0-alpha11-4662957-windows.jar\67f4bb4ae3aea8a18831d06eb5615105\aapt2-3.2.0-alpha11-4662957-windows\aapt2.exe compile --legacy \
      -o \
C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\haha\app\build\intermediates\res\merged\debug \
      C:\Windows\System32\config\systemprofile\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\appcompat-v7-28.0.0-alpha3.aar\6bb4f54973fdd09ea38bd7415ec1d0d5\res\layout\abc_action_bar_up_container.xml
```

Comment: Please do not post code and/or errors as image

Comment: @MikhailKholodkov I have enclosed it in code area. Can you please help

Comment: Did you check out this question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51202130/android-resource-compilation-failed-in-3-3-0-alpha02

Comment: @MikhailKholodko I have already applied all the settings. The error i'm getting is from System 32 cached gradle file,that i'm not getting.

Comment: Try building with android gradle plugin version 3.2.0-alpha11 or newer, there was a bunch of windows specific fixes in aapt2 that went into this version (aapt2 is now published in google maven, instead of using the one in build tools).

Answer (score 0):

Fix by not using System32 as a cache. From [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47471777/error-when-compiling-with-gradle-cant-find-downloaded-dependencies) there are two solutions to this:

1. Set the `GRADLE_USER_HOME` environmental variable
2. Add `-g C:\*some dir*` to the command

Answer (score 0):

Facing this issue with Jenkins in windows, I fixed this issue by setting Environmental variable to Gradle as fixed my issue.

> GRADLE_USER_HOME as C:/gradle-cache