# Fail while build with Gradle on TeamCity: Task :app:processDebugResources FAILED

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gradle, teamcity

I build my Android project by Gradle builder in command line:

```
Gradlew build
```

Everything works:

```
BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 4s
54 actionable tasks: 1 executed, 53 up-to-date
```

but at the same project, same environment, does error while build in TeamCity:

```
Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'. org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.DefaultLenientConfiguration$ArtifactResolveException: Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.'
```

many many artifacts not found like this:

```
What went wrong:
[org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
[org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] > Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
[org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]    > Failed to transform artifact 'appcompat.aar (androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0)' to match attributes {artifactType=android-compiled-dependencies-resources}.
[org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]       > Execution failed for AarResourcesCompilerTransform: C:\Windows\System32\config\systemprofile\.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\f7fa931c10060cb31b4ececcd856b65d\appcompat-1.1.0.
[org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]          > Android resource compilation failed
[org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]            AAPT: C:\Windows\System32\config\systemprofile\.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\7340c553bf3aabb8e86abd5cba76d4e6\androidx.appcompat: error: The system cannot find the file specified. (2).
```

I try run `clean build` or `build` command, but it does not work.

also I add a line into Gradle.properties for turn off gradle daemon:

```
add org.gradle.daemon=false
```

gradle-wrapper.properties:

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-5.6.4-all.zip
```

Build.gradle:

```
dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.6.1
```

Could it be because the project is located remotely on GitHub and needs additional scripts?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2bnHF.png)

Comment: You most likely have cached locally what cannot be resolved anymore. Question: On what machine does your TeamCity run? Your error message contains something that looks like a dev machine local path: "C:\Windows\System32\config\systemprofile\.gradle\caches\".

Try to clean your local gradle cache and see if you can reproduce the problem locally. Otherwise check references for local files in your build script.

Comment: @Kekzpanda, thank You for pointing me in the right direction. TeamCity run on my local machine. 
I clean Gradle cach folder - C:\Users\Administrator\.gradle\caches
Also I clean worker TeamCity - C:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work
Also I clean Gradle daemons - C:\Users\Administrator\.gradle\daemon
Also I clean Gradle another cash folder (Gradle makes its cache everywhere, even under my bed:)) - C:\Windows\System32\config\systemprofile\.gradle\caches

Finally, it does not work.

Comment: Also I run Gradle build from TeamCity used local repository 'file://C:/Users/Administrator/PanariksChat/.git'
Same fail.

Comment: Unfortunately, I do not have experience with TeamCity on Windows or local machines. However, it still sounds like a permission issue. How about running all of outside of a windows or user folder? Maybe setup everything in C:\projects\myProject and having gradle in C:\programs\gradle. OR/AND make sure teamcity runs with administrative privileges. Maybe the "Administrator" user and their folder are a cause. Furthermore, maybe you can enhance the gradle build process with more verbosity or debug flags, to get more information on the cause. (just wild guessing here)

Comment: This post helps me to solve my problem: [Error-when-compiling-with-gradle-cant-find-downloaded-dependencies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47471777/error-when-compiling-with-gradle-cant-find-downloaded-dependencies)

Comment: Was it the file path length? Windows truly is the OS of pitfalls.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue and solved it by adding the following parameters to my Teamcity project.

Environment Variable
JAVA_HOME -                 The path to the Java JDK on your local machine
D:\Android Studio\jre

ANDROID_HOME -               The path to the Android SDK on your local machine
C:\Users\kelvin\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk